# Java: Can you downcast with a variable?

Tags: java, variables, derived-class, downcast

If I have a few derived classes that have methods that are different than the base class, but similar to each other, **can I use a variable to downcast?**

*for example:*

```
    Object derivedClass = baseClass.getChild().getClass();
    ((derivedClass)differentClassObj.differentClassMethod()).derivedClassMethod();
```

Perhaps that's too vague and/or not efficient since I could just create empty methods in the base class to bypass this issue (or other tricks I haven't learned), but I'm still curious if it's possible to pass variables into casting or not.

Thanks for your insight!

**Edit:** to further clarify any confusion, I'm trying to determine if I can do casting using a variable. So say I wanted to cast something as a String (just for argument's sake):

```
    String myObjStr = MyObject.class.getSimpleName();
    // Then I want to know if I can cast objects using that variable in the casting 
    //(so far it doesn't appear to be working but I know that's because its a string. 
    //Is there some way I can manipulate it so that I CAN cast with it?)
    ((myObjStr).differentClassObj.differentClassMethod()).derivedClassMethod();
```

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking, but you *could* use **reflection** to determine if any instance has a visible `derivedClassMethod()` and invoke it if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can sort of use a Class object to specify what type to cast an object to, it doesn't really help you:

```
Class<? extends ParentClass> derivedClass = baseClassObject.getChild().getClass();

// The following kind of does the cast you want, but not in a useful way:
derivedClass.cast(differentClassObject)
```

The problem is that you still need to statically know the type of the result. The static type of the `cast` output is only as specific as the *static* type of the `Class` object, not the class the `Class` object actually represents. Thus, even if you have a `derivedClass` object representing `ChildClassOne`, you only know that it's a `Class<? extends ParentClass>`. While the object's `cast` method will throw an exception for instances of `ChildClassTwo`, you can't call `ChildClassOne` methods on the return value.

If all instances of classes in this class hierarchy will have the method you're looking for, but the base class cannot provide a useful implementation, you should mark the base class abstract and give it this method as an abstract method. If some objects in this class hierarchy will not have the method you're looking for, you should probably redesign your program or perform casts the regular way. Introducing an interface might be a good idea. Whatever the case, casting with a `Class` object probably won't help you.

Comment: Well shoot, sounds like it won't do what I wanted, but this was mostly for my own personal curiosity so I appreciate you taking the time to explain it. You've given me some other things to research and explore. thanks! :D